# GitLab post-receive hook not firing

Tags: git, gitlab

Apologies if this isn't the right stackexchange.

I have a GitLab install. It was installed over the top of a gitolite install that was only a few days old, and I assume this non-standard setup is at the root of my problem, but I cannot pin it down.

The problem is straightforward: post-receive hooks are not fired. This prevents 'project activity' appearing in GitLab. The problem looks like:

```
$ git push
#...
error: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory
```

**Hook Exists**

The post-receive hook/symlink exists and is executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 git git 470 Oct  3  2012 .gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive
lrwxrwxrwx 1 git git  45 Oct  3  2012 repositories/project.git/hooks/post-receive -> /home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive
```

**It's Executable By GitLab**

The gitlab user can execute the script (I have removed the `/dev/null` redirect and fed in blank input to get an 'OK' as output):

```
sudo su - gitlab -c /home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive

OK
```

**GitLab Can Find It**

GitLab is looking for hooks in the correct location:

```
$ grep hooks /srv/gitlab/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml
  hooks_path: /home/git/.gitolite/hooks/
```

and

```
$ bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production
# ...
/home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive exists? ............YES
```

**GitLab Runs As Correct User**

The GitLab software is being run by the gitlab user:

```
$ ps U gitlab
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3650 ?        Sl     0:59 unicorn_rails master -c /srv/gitlab/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
 3671 ?        Sl     0:43 unicorn_rails worker[0] -c /srv/gitlab/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
 3674 ?        Sl     0:42 unicorn_rails worker[1] -c /srv/gitlab/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
# ...
```

**Environment**

The `env -i` line in the hook is commonly cited as an issue. I think that would occur *after* this problem, but for completeness, `redis-cli` is found OK:

```
$ env -i redis-cli
redis>
```

I've run out of debugging ideas on this one. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, figured this one out. It's remotely possible this situation will apply to other people, so I've documented it.

Our infrastructure has all external SSH connections landing on a particular machine<sup>1</sup>. This isn't the machine running gitlab. This wasn't obvious because gitolite+gitlab works despite this. Our homedirs are NFS mounts and both the SSH machine and the gitlab machine see the gitolite files as 'local'. The one problem with this 'distributed' gitolite+gitlab is that the `post-receive` hook tries to call `redis-cli`, a binary which doesn't exist on the machine running the hook.

To solve the problem, I installed the `redis-server` package on the machine accepting SSH connections (unfortunately the `redis-cli` binary doesn't appear to be available separately). I then modified the redis line in `/home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive` to the following:

```
redis-cli -h hostname rpush "resque:queue:post_receive" "{\"class\":\"PostReceive\",\"args\":[\"$reponame\",\"$oldrev\",\"$newrev\",\"$ref\",\"$GL_USER\"]}" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The `-h hostname` switch is the only addition. This causes the redis rpush command to be sent to redis on the correct machine.

The missing binary error didn't surface due to the `> /dev/null 2>&1` redirect in the hook script. Although I did remove it during debugging, I must have restored it before I attempted to trigger the hook via a `git push`, which otherwise would have echoed the error.

My assumption about my slightly nonstandard gitlab installation turned out to be incorrect. This problem would have occured regardless; it's due to a networking quirk. Anyhow, I hope this will be of use to somebody.

1. In the case of git, we use external URLs even within the local network so that project URLs are consistent regardless of network environment.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but the reason was different.

My `redis` installation was at `/usr/local/bin`. Git user had it in its `PATH`, but with no effect.

I had to make it obvious in script to start redis from `/usr/local/bin/redis-cli`:

```
env -i /usr/local/bin/redis-cli rpush "resque:queue:post_receive" "{\"class\":\"PostReceive\",\"args\":[\"$reponame\",\"$oldrev\",\"$newrev\",\"$ref\",\"$GL_USER\"]}"  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

It solved my issue with post-receive hook not firing.

I hope this will be helpful for someone else too.

Comment: I believe it's the `env -i` switch causing your problem: "start with an empty environment". There is a bug report here: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/669

Comment: Well, you are definitely right. Here this issue marked as fixed: [#621](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/621), but my GitLab 3 fresh install did not have this patched post-recieve hook. Perhaps this is because I previously had Gitolite installation.